# Locus in Complex plane

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, vectors

Could someone help me out with this one

Show that the locus of w as z varies with |z| = 1, where w is given by
$$w^2=\frac {1-z}{1+z}$$
is a pair of straight lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help to get you started:
let $z = e^{i \theta} = \cos \theta + i \sin \theta$ where $\theta \in [0,2\pi)$.  We have
$$
\begin{align}
w^2 &= \frac{1 - z}{1 + z} = 
\frac{1 - e^{i\theta}}{1 + e^{i \theta}}\cdot
\frac{1 + e^{-i\theta}}{1 + e^{-i\theta}}\\
&= \frac{-e^{i\theta} + e^{-i\theta}}{2 + e^{i \theta} + e^{-i \theta}}
= -i\frac{\sin \theta}{1+\cos \theta}
\end{align}
$$
Since $w^2$ is purely imaginary, it follows that $|\operatorname{Re}(w)| = |\operatorname{Im}(w)|$.  Now, show that this locus is the set of all such points.